# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in MessagesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Good day, I am trying to create a chat section on my website but I keep on getting `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in MessagesController#create`

```
unknown attribute 'user_id' for Message.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here,

my route is

```
resources :conversations do
  resources :messages
end
```

Here is my conversations model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :recipient_id
  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do 
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND   conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

And in the Message model, app/models/message.rb: I have

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
end
```

In the Conversations controller, app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb: I have

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end
  def create  
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present? 
       @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
       @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end
  private
  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end
end
```

I think the main issue is in my conversation index page on the line that links to a message page `@message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)`
In the Message controller, app/controllers/messages_controller.rb: I have

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
  
  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end
  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end
  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end
  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

In app/views/conversations/index.html.erb

```
<h1>My Inbox</h1>
<h1>All Conversations:</h1>
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
 <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
  <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
   <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
  <% else %>
   <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
  <% end %>
  <h3><%= link_to recipient.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%></h3>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<h1>All Users:</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <% if user.id != current_user.id %><h3>
 <%= link_to user.email, conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method: "post"%></h3>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In app/views/messages/index.html.erb I have

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
 <% if message.body %>
  <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>
  <%= user.email %><%= message.message_time %>
  <%= message.body %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
 <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can guild me on what to do right and is this a good way to setup a chat system?

Comment: Can you show how the `conversation` and `messages` resources are defined in `config/routes.rb`? Rails generates the `*_path` helpers based on how you have defined your routes.

Comment: Ohhh, I don't know how I forgot that, I have set my route to `resources :conversations do resources :messages end`

Comment: Now I am getting `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in MessagesController#create
unknown attribute 'user_id' for Message.` I will just edit the question to answer this issue.

Comment: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError` is raised when you're missing an a database column. You need to create (if it doesnt already exist) a migration to add the `user_id` column to messages table. You also have to run the migration.